# how to show offline.html on ios PWA

Tags: html, ios, safari, progressive-web-apps, offline

i´m working on a PWA app (android and ios optimized) and cannot get the offline.html on ios to work.
I´m working with webmanifest and ServiceWorker.

Here is my code from index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TestStore</title>
    <script src="index.js" defer></script>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">
    <script async src="https://unpkg.com/pwacompat" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="style_menue.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="TestStore" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
  <body>
.......
```

i register service worker in index.js

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
           .register('/sw.js')
           .then(function() { console.log('Service Worker Registered');});
}
```

and here is my service worker (sw.js)

```
const OFFLINE_VERSION = 1;
const CACHE_NAME = 'offline';
const OFFLINE_URL = 'offline.html';

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil((async () => {
    const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
    await cache.add(new Request(OFFLINE_URL, {cache: 'reload'}));
  })());
});
self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil((async () => {
    if ('navigationPreload' in self.registration) {
      await self.registration.navigationPreload.enable();
    }
  })());
  self.clients.claim();
});
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
    event.respondWith((async () => {
      try {
        const preloadResponse = await event.preloadResponse;
        if (preloadResponse) {
          return preloadResponse;
        }

        const networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
        return networkResponse;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Fetch failed; returning offline page instead.', error);
        const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        const cachedResponse = await cache.match(OFFLINE_URL);
        return cachedResponse;
      }
    })());
  }
});
```

Here is my manifest.webmanifest

```
{
  "background_color": "white",
  "description": "My first Store",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icon/fox-icon.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "name": "TestStore",
  "short_name": "TestStore",
  "start_url": "/"
}
```

Chrome is showing the offline.html but safari not.

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: Problem solved. The PWA was running in XAMPP without SSL. You need SSL to run service worker correctly.